# Child XML for Joomla Parameters

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm creating a template with many parameters available in its backend. 
Basically I have about 8 blocks in the template structure (index.php) and each block have about 30 options (background, content type, layout, animation etc) so I have about 300 options totally in the template backend. This makes the template backend is loaded very slow when opened or saved.

Is there any native way (I didn't use any template framework) to make all of these 30 options are loaded in the separated / child xml so it will be called by demand (ajax) and the template backend loaded faster? Any other suggestion or advice are welcome

Answer (score 0):

There is no "native" way to do what you want. I do think, however, that Joomla is slow in rendering these XML tags so it might be worth it to check the code that does the rendering and perhaps optimize it.